# Overlay menu in iOS like Comcast Xfinity iPad app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In the Comcast Xfinity iPad app, there is a small button called "Filter by" at the bottom of the screen.

When a user touch the button, a overlay menu will slide up (like the menu UI in Android).

Can anyone give me some hints about how to create this kind of overlay menu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can create a UIView in your nib and make it look like the menu you need, then in viewdidload you can set its origin to be just off the screen and when you want it to appear just use an animation to slide it up into view and then slide it back off the screen when you're done.

In viewDidLoad:

```
CGRect frame = [your_menu_view].frame;
frame.origin.y += frame.size.height;
[your_menu_view].frame = frame;
```

When you are ready to show it:

```
NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.3;//play around with the animation length here
CGRect frame = [your_menu_view].frame;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"MenuSlideIn" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
frame.origin -= frame.size.height;
[your_menu_view].frame = frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Then use the same to get rid of it except subtract add its height.

haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: I added the code that should work to the answer. Let me know how it goes.